# How to change app/public to app/something in Laravel storage

Tags: laravel

It's very strange. I change in filesystems.php

```
'FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'
```

and

```
'root' => storage_path('app/files')
```

Then run command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

But when I write in blade

```
{{ asset('storage/files/picture.png') }}
```

a picture don't show.
When I open page source code, than I see

```
<img src="http://site.ru/storage/files/picture.png" >
```

But it doesn't show. Why?

Folder structure:

```
site.ru\storage\app\files\picture.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the [`storage:link` command](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e04a7ffba8b80b934506783a7d0a161dd52eb2ef/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/StorageLinkCommand.php#L34) is hard coded to link the `app/public` folder.
However, you can manually create the link to your custom folder and it should work fine as well.